# How to kill node process within mocha test

Tags: node.js

Within my tests, I'm using require('child_process').exec to run "npm run start-app" which starts up a webpack-dev-server. After my tests have run I want to kill the process that I have started.

Currently I am able to successfully kill the process when running "mocha tests.js" directly. However, when I run the tests using "npm run tests" which calls "mocha tests.js", the process is not killed. Is this because the node process is blocking me from killing the process?

I am killing the process by discovering pids using ps-tree and using a kill -9 or taskkill depending on operating system.

```
    test.after(function () {
        psTree(appStartProcess.pid, function (err, children) {
            if(/^win/.test(process.platform)) {
                for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    exec('taskkill /pid ' + children[i].PID + ' /T /F');
                }
            } else{
                cp.spawn('kill', ['-9'].concat(children.map(function (p) {
                    return p.PID;
                })));
            }
        });
    });
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: I've solved this before with global `before` and `after` blocks that start a process (and store some reference to it) and then kill it.

Comment: Hey nick that is basically what I am doing which works when I run the test directly. Once I use npm run test as a wrapper, the processes are not killed.... How did you run your test using npm run ?

Comment: Hmm I would probably move in the direction of creating an event emitter or socket that listens for a kill child command in the socket and clean exits when the command is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ChildProcess`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) returned by `spawn` after our test to `kill` it afterwards.

Given the following server to act as a running process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('http').createServer((_, res) => {
  res.end('Hi from process')
}).listen(3000, console.log)
```

Your tests might look like this:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process')

// this would typically be done in a separate helper
// that mocha executes before your tests
before(function (done) {
  // `this` is the shared mocha execution context
  this.runningProcess = exec('test/server.js')
  setTimeout(done, 500)
})

after(function () {
  this.runningProcess.kill()
})

describe('my tests', () => {
  it('properly initializes process', (done) => {
    require('http').get({
      port: 3000,
      agent: false
    }, (res) => {
      let data = ''
      res
        .setEncoding('utf8')
        .on('data', chunk => data += chunk)
        .on('end', () => {
          require('assert')(data === 'Hi from process')
          done()
        })
    })
  })
})
```

Alternately, you can use something outside of mocha (e.g. a custom script that starts your server, runs mocha, and then shuts your server down) but the concept is essentially the same.